# Datamapper ORM with memcache

Tags: php, orm, memcached, datamapper

I am using the wonderful ORM library at http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/ in a PHP project. Is there a way to integrate memcache into this? I have enabled the config for the datamapper cache but this is just for the models.

Apologies ahead of time as this will be posted on their bitbucket page to ensure the author sees this. https://bitbucket.org/wanwizard/datamapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no. Datamapper is 6 year old code, and very difficult to adapt. I would use an external caching library.

I no longer maintain Datamapper, and nobody has stood up to take it over, so don't expect any changes or improvements soon...

Comment: Thanks... it is still a great library. What would you use in it's place?